# finding specific character from substring

Tags: string, apache-flex, flash-builder4.5

I have this function to find string for the first time:

```
var strng:String = new String(txtSource.text)
var position:Number = new Number();
position = strng.indexOf("<img pg",0);          
strng = strng.substring(position + 4);
position = strng.indexOf(">");
strng = strng.substring(0, position);
textcontrol1.text = String(strng);
```

Now I get below string as answer

```
<img pg="asStoryVid" class="" vspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" width="300" border="0" src="http://www.abc.com/thumb/msid-22087805,width-300,resizemode-4/xyz.jpg" 
alt="" title="" ag="">
```

Now, further I want only src="http://www.abc.com/thumb/msid-22087805,width-300,resizemode-4/xyz.jpg" from above string. For that I have write this function

```
var strng1:String = new String(textcontrol1.text)
var position1:Number = new Number();
position1 = strng1.indexOf('src="http://',0);                   
strng1 = strng1.substring(position1 + 0);
position1 = strng1.indexOf('"');
strng1 = strng1.substring(0, position1);
textcontrol1.text = String(strng1);
```

But in output I getting a no string
Any one can show me where I m wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
var strng1:String = new String(textcontrol1.text);
var position1:Number = new Number();
position1 = strng1.indexOf('src="http://',0);
strng1 = strng1.substring(position1 + 0);
// search 2nd " character
position1 = strng1.indexOf('"', strng1.indexOf('"') + 1);

strng1 = strng1.substring(0, position1 + 1);

textcontrol1.text = String(strng1);
```

Answer (score 0):

No no no - just [use a regex](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html#exec()):

```
var str:String = '<img pg="asStoryVid" class="" vspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" width="300" border="0" src="http://www.abc.com/thumb/msid-22087805,width-300,resizemode-4/xyz.jpg" alt="" title="" ag="">';
//var str:String = new String(textcontrol1.text);
var pattern:RegExp = /<img [^>]*src="([^"]+)"/i; 
var result:Object = pattern.exec(str);

if (result) {
    //textcontrol1.text = result[1];
    trace(result[1]);
}
```

The `[^>]*` means: zero or more characters, but not closing bracket `>`

The `[^"]+` means: one or more characters, but not a quote

And the round brackets capture it into `result[1]`

And as a general advice: keep your regexes simple by not putting stuff into them that you don't need to capture (i.e. do not add `class=` or `width=` to your regex).